# how can i use values in array ? (php)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I wanna use values in array of array like:

```
$result  = $conn->query("SELECT performer,file_id,title,duration FROM 
    databasebot WHERE performer = '$message' or title = '$message'");

$poets = array(
    "keyboard" => array()
);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {        
    $poets['keyboard'][] = array($row[2],$row[1]);         
}
```

I wanna echo $poets values of $row[1]. How can I do that?

Comment: We need some context.  Where did `$poets` come from?

Comment: Why too many levels/depth of array? `[]` and `array()`?

Comment: @Thamilan He's creating a 2-dimensional array. `[]` is to push onto the `keyboard` array.

Comment: @BonsaiOak edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array in `$poets['keyboard']`. In each element, `$poets[1]` will be in the `[1]` sub-element.

```
foreach ($poets['keyboard'] as $kb) {
    echo $kb[1];
}
```